# Tabs disappear when change size of window apex

Tags: oracle11g, themes, oracle-apex

When I change width of fire-fox window to thinner part of tabs located on top of page disappear. How to change that to keep them at page, display unconditionally? I'll scroll page right using scrollbar located on the bottom of browser window. I use theme Topaz 4 in APEX 4.2.5. oracle XE 11.2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: Go to shared components, then themes. Select the theme you are using and then go to the page template you are using. In the body area look for the substitution strings #PARENT_TAB_CELLS# and/or #TAB_CELLS#. This is the place in your template where the tabs will be displayed as the page is rendered. Try encapsulating these with a DIV with a static width, wide enough to contain all your tabs. For example:

```
<div style="width:800px;">#PARENT_TAB_CELLS#</div>
```

Use your browser devtools to find the right width. You might also have to play around with alignments a bit.